# Building project with clion

Tags: build, clion

I tried to build a project with clion. My coworker did it with ease, his version is the same. I get a strange error message

[image: 1]

I tried googling it but didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I created a usability problem about the non user-friendly message - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-31572.

The thing is that you have no CMake profiles (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html)configured. Please go to `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake` and add a profile there.